# Uncomprehensible out of Memory Error with Logstash

Tags: docker, out-of-memory, logstash

I have a **Logstash 7.6.2 docker** that stops running because of memory leak. After each pipeline execution, it looks like Logstash doesn't release memory.
**What should I do to identify the source of the problem?
How can I solve it?**

Any help is welcom ^^.

Here is the error I see in the logs. These are just the 5 first lines of the Traceback. I uploaded the rest in a file in my github [there](https://github.com/yviouswilliamous/Logstash-error/blob/master/logstash_traceback.txt).

```
logstash    | [2020-04-08T18:15:42,960][INFO ][logstash.outputs.file    ][rawweb] Closing file /output/web_data.json
 logstash    | [2020-04-08T18:15:43,353][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 logstash    | [2020-04-08T18:15:43,367][ERROR][org.logstash.execution.WorkerLoop][rawclient] Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash.
 logstash    | org.jruby.exceptions.NoMethodError: (NoMethodError) undefined method `pop' for nil:NilClass
 logstash    |   at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.awesome_print_minus_1_dot_7_dot_0.lib.awesome_print.inspector.awesome(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:117) ~[?:?]
```

Here the **docker-compose.yml** I used to configure my Logstash Docker

```
version: '2.4'    
services:
      logstash:
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.6.2
        container_name: logstash
        environment:
          LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx7g -Xms4g"
          REQUEST_FREQUENCY: 600 #seconds
        volumes:
          - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
          - ./logstash/pipelines.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
          - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
          - ./logstash/tests:/testscripts:ro
          - /root/logstash_output/:/output/
        ports:
          - "9600:9600"
        mem_limit: 7000M
        mem_reservation: 100M
```

My **pipelines.yml** file

```
- pipeline.id: rawclient
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logclient.conf"
  pipeline.batch.size: 10000000

 - pipeline.id: rawweb
   path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logweb.conf"
   pipeline.batch.size: 10000000
```

One of my **.conf** files. Basically, it executes a **.sh** script containing a curl request. The result of this request is the input of the pipeline. Treatments are made. Then results are stored in file. The two pipelines do the same, the only difference is the curl request that is made.

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "bash /testscripts/logclient_1.sh"
    codec => "json"
    interval => "600"
  }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        rename => ["connection/start_time", "start_time" ]
        rename => ["connection/end_time", "end_time" ]
        rename => ["connection/duration", "duration" ]
        rename => ["connection/destination_ip_address", "destination_ip_address" ]
        rename => ["connection/status", "status" ]
        rename => ["device/last_ip_address", "last_ip_address" ]
        rename => ["user/sid", "sid" ]
        # rename => ["binary/application_category", "application_category" ]
        rename => ["binary/application_name", "application_name" ]
        rename => ["binary/executable_name", "executable_name" ]
        remove_field => ["@timestamp"]
        remove_field => ["@version"]
        add_field => { "connection_type" => "client" }
    }
}
output {
  file {
   path => "/output/client_data.json"
   codec => "json"
 }
  stdout {
   codec => rubydebug
 }
}
```

My **logstash.yml** file

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
Thanks for all the help :slightly_smiling_face:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipeline batch size is **huge**. Here's what the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html) says about this setting:

> The maximum number of events an individual worker thread will collect from inputs before attempting to execute its filters and outputs. Larger batch sizes are generally more efficient, but come at the cost of increased memory overhead. You may need to increase JVM heap space in the jvm.options config file.

This means that **an individual worker** will collect 10 million events **before** starting to process them. Obviously these 10 million events have to be kept in memory. Furthermore, you have an additional pipeline with the same batch size of 10 million events. Thats huge considering that you have only 7 GB of RAM given to Logstash. Also note that the default is **125 events**.

I would suggest to decrease the batch sizes of your pipelines to fix the OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Comment: @Sevy You're welcome, glad I could help you! I'd really appreciate if you would consider accepting my answer.